# Vagrant dev env forwarding requests to staging and filtering & replacing certain files with local versions

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, tinyproxy

I want to create a Vagrant dev environment where a dev would be able to hit `dev.example.com` and the vagrant machine would make the same request to `staging.example.com` except filter out some files, say app.js and main.css and serve those from local fs.

There are too many api dependancies reeking havoc for smooth local development.

This is possible? Any tips or suggestions would also be helpful as well